# Dropdown with selected value, using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having a form on a modal filled out, then creating a form on the same html page and filling the form with the information from the modal form.

All of the inputs fill fine, and on another page, the dropdown fills fine using just ng-model.

However, when this form shows up, the dropdown is on the selected value but it isnt able to be changed or clicked. Its just a static value. I want it to be able to be changed to the other values in the list. The dropdown has an arrow showings its a dropdown but when clicked it doesnt dropdown.

self.alert.measureType is bound with ng-model to a dropdown in the form on the modal that gets filled out.There is only 2 values in self.measurements, Meters and Kilometers.

Here is the dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" style="background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow; border-color: black;" ng-model="self.alert.measureType">
    <option value="" style="color: #ccc !important" disabled> -Select- </option>
    <option ng-repeat="type in self.measurements" value="{{type}}"> {{type}} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your controller following this.
Assign the value your model in selected value
$scope.self.alert.measureType = "Meters"